# How to run a bash script from a Dockerfile on a Mac

Tags: bash, macos, docker

I'm trying to run a bash script from a Docker Image on a Mac. Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM bash
ADD app.sh /
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "/app.sh"]
```

Error

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "/bin/bash": stat /bin/bash: no such file or directory: unknown.
```

This is a simple exercise in creating Docker Images where I need to execute app.sh when I run docker run.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your error message, the file `/bin/bash` does not exist in your Docker image. Why is this?

The bash image puts the bash executable at `/usr/local/bin/bash`. Here's how I determined this:

```
$ docker run -it bash
bash-5.1# which bash
/usr/local/bin/bash
bash-5.1#
```

I ran the bash image with `-it` to make it interactive, then used the `which` command to give me the full path to bash, which is `/usr/local/bin/bash`.

For that reason, you need to change your Dockerfile like this:

```
FROM bash
ADD app.sh /
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/bash", "/app.sh"]
```